# Pygame scrolling background disappearing?

Tags: python, scroll, background, pygame

I'm making a game in Pygame, and the background is scrolling. But it keeps disappearing! It scrolls for two times and then it disappears. How do I fix this?? Here is the code:

```
#Scrolling background

    background = "foxhabitat.jpg"
    back = pygame.image.load(background).convert()
    back2 = pygame.image.load(background).convert()

    screenWidth = 900
    back=pygame.transform.scale(back, (1000,600))
    back2=pygame.transform.scale(back, (1000,600))   

    screenscroll.blit(back, (xx,0))
    screenscroll.blit(back2,(xx+screenWidth,0))
    print xx
    xx = xx - 12
    if xx >= screenWidth:
        xx = 0

    msElapsed = clock.tick(100) # changes speed of scrolling
```

Comment: btw: you don't need `back2` you can blit `back` two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
if xx >= screenWidth:
    xx = 0
```

should be

```
if xx + screenWidth <= 0:
    xx = 0
```

`xx` starts at `0`, then you substract `12` from it every time. The result is that `xx` is always `<= 0`, so `xx >= screenWidth` will always be false.

`xx + screenWidth` is the position of the *second* image, and when that value becomes smaller than zero, it is time to reset the `xx` position to let the scrolling begin again.

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract then you can't compare with `screenWidth` but with `0` (zero)

```
xx = xx - 12
if xx <= 0:
    xx = screenWidth
```

or you can do

```
xx = xx - 12
if xx <= 0:
    xx = xx + screenWidth
```

Comment: I've tried both of those but it still didn't work, the scrolling background still disappears. What else can I do to fix this?